# How to calculate the error on the ratio of a counting experiment?

Tags: error, count-data, ratio

In an experiment I repeat some task $n$ times and count how often the task completes successfully. This gives the number $m$. Therefore the success ratio is

$$
r = \frac{m}{n}
$$

To calculate the error I just would use

$$
\Delta r = \frac{\Delta m}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{m}}{n}
$$

but then when I have for example $n=10$ trials with all trials successfully ($m=10$) I would get a success rate of 100% with error 31.6 %, meaning the real success rate is larger than  68.3%.

But on the other side the failure rate would be 0% with error 0% implying there could never be an error, which is incorrect. Also it is unsymmetrical.

So how to properly calculate the errors on the success/failure rate so that I can make statements like

```
The success rate is larger then X %
The failure rate is smaller than Y %
```

Comment: You told us what metric are you using and asked about another metric. The problem is that there are many metrics, each measuring a different thing, neither of them is more "proper" than another. So the question is what do you want to measure? What should the properties of this metric be? How do you want to use this metric?

Comment: I want to quantify the success rate/failure rate of a process, i.e. I want to be able to say that (within ""1 sigma"") the success rate is higher than X%, or to say the failure rate of a process is lower than Y %.

Comment: It is unclear to me where your $\frac{\sqrt{m}}{n}$ came from, but it does not look satisfactory.  You seem to be looking for something like [binomial proportion confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach is via Laplace's Rule of Succession.

For $m$ successes and $n-m$ failures, the probability for success for the *next* trial is $$p=\frac{m+1}{n+2}.$$
This means for $m=10$ and $n=10$ a success rate of $p=11/12$ or $p\simeq0.92$. Hence the probability for a failure is still 0.08.

This approach is part of Bayesian statistics.
Anyone interested should have a look at *Information Processing*, Volume 1, by David J. Blower.

Comment: If you take that approach, implicitly the mean of the posterior Beta distribution starting with a uniform prior for the success probability, then its standard deviation would be $\sqrt{\frac{(m+1)(n-m+1)}{(n+2)^2(n+3)}}$, which with $n=10$ and either $m=0$ or $m=10$ would be about $0.077$